# how can i replace something inside a txt file (python)

Tags: python, file, replace, txt

i am trying to replace something in my txt file without deleting anything else in that file.
so i want to split at the "=" sign and then replace everything that comes after it with a variable called "new_balance"

```
        with open("{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author)) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                fragments = line.split("=", maxsplit=1)
                candidate = fragments[0].strip()
                if candidate == "Coins":
                    if candidate in line:
                        line = line.replace(fragments[1], new_balance)
                    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

my txt file looks something like this:
`verified! Coins=0 Attack=0 Defense==`

everything that comes after Coins= should be replaced with the new_balance variable

Comment: lmao you the guy from the discord server

Comment: how does the txt file look like?

Comment: Simple: write the lines to a new temporary textfile and then delete the original file and rename the new textfile.

Comment: Can you add a line in the description to show the desired result?

Comment: @PavanVaryani the new_balance is the sum of the coin i currently have and the coins that have spawned. 

i want the number behind the = sign in the line where the keyword Coins is to change from what it currently is to new_balance

verified! Coins Attack and Defense are each in a single line

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = []
temp = line.split("=", maxsplit=1)
line = temp[0] + "=" + str(new_balance) + " " + temp[1].split(" ", maxsplit=1)[1]
```

temp output: ['verified! Coins', '0 Attack', '0 Defense', '', '']

line output: verified! Coins=1 Attack=0 Defense==